# Changing itemprop from logo to image on custom logo?

Tags: functions, theme-development, logo

I'm adding schema.org markups to my theme's header, but the theme I'm using is calling `the_custom_logo();`, and by default it uses 'logo' as `itemprop`.

Is there anyway to change this to `image` in the `functions.php` file?

Thanks.

This is the current calling function from the functions.php file.

```
add_theme_support('custom-logo');
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. Please find and post that function from your theme's functions.php file. Then i can write a function for you to use in a child theme.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer. So, I guess it's just using WordPress's defaults on the function. Please could you let me know how I could change the default 'itemprop="logo"' to 'itemprop="image"'. Thanks.

Comment: That really doesn't matter. All you need to do is create a code from the_custom_logo() that alters the itemprop from logo to image. It doesn't matter what HTML it's outputting. And from my initial question, you can clearly see that the HTML goes something like, ITEMPROP LOGO!

Comment: I updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have problem with google validator about `itemprop="logo"`. You can hook into the `get_custom_header` filter and alter the HTML structure:

```
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'my_custom_logo' );
// Filter the output of logo to fix Googles Error about itemprop logo
function my_custom_logo() {
    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
            wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, array(
                'class'    => 'custom-logo',
            ) )
        );
    return $html;   
}
```

Add the above code to your theme's `functions.php` or follow the steps [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to create a child theme and use this code in it's `functions.php` file.

### Edit

Based on @birgire's comment, i wrote another function to filter the `wp_get_attachment_image()`:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image', function ($attachment_id, $size , $icon , $attr) {
        // If the class is 'custom-logo', then change the itemprop to image
        if ($attr['class'] =='custom-logo') {
            $attr['itemprop'] = 'image';
        }
        return $attr;
},10,3);
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but this doesn't change it.

Comment: @Jake You should be able to resolve the error by removing the `itemprop` from the function.

Comment: You could also filter the attributes with the `wp_get_attachment_image` filer and change the `itemprop` attribute to `image`, if it's `logo` and the class is `custom-logo`. That way we avoid calling `wp_get_attachment_image()` twice..

Comment: Hi @birgire ! Do you have any idea why the above code won't work on his case? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Hopefully OP can provide better debug info.

Comment: ps: the return must be outside the `if` parentheses, otherwise it can return null. Also I wonder if `only overriding the $attr['itemprop']` with `'image'` would be enough, instead of overriding `$attr` totally?

Comment: @birgire Thanks. I also forgot the set the priority. This is one of my weaknesses, i have to update a code 999 times, each time adding a single letter.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a weakness, I would say incremental changes are usually better and show that you care to learn and improve. I've e.g. never heard of a painter that doesn't incrementally improve her painting in many small steps ;-)

Comment: @birgire Thank you. I like how you determined the painter's gender already ;) (sorry i know i shouldn't comment irrelevant notes, but couldn't resist anymore after struggling for 20 minutes.)